# Tastypie how to get custom Json Response after injecting Post data

Tags: json, django, tastypie

i want to have custom json response after data post sendind to my Tastypie API models django.

```
class MyModelResource(ModelResource):

my_field=""
class Meta:
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'nick_name'
    authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
    authorization = DjangoAuthorization()


def hydrate(self, bundle):
    #on recupere les donnée injectée par bundle.data['title']
    #et on inject les donnée via bundle.obj.title


    #bundle.data['my_field'] ="1234"
    bundle.obj.my_field=bundle.data['my_field']
    self.my_field = bundle.data['my_field']



    return bundle





def wrap_view(self, view):
    """
    Wraps views to return custom error codes instead of generic 500's
    """
    @csrf_exempt
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            callback = getattr(self, view)
            response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

            if request.is_ajax():
                patch_cache_control(response, no_cache=True)



            lst_dic=[]
            mon_dic = dict(success=True,  my_field=self.my_field


                       )
            # response is a HttpResponse object, so follow Django's instructions
            # to change it to your needs before you return it.
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/
            lst_dic.append(mon_dic)   

            response = HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(lst_dic), content_type='application/json')
            return response
        except (BadRequest, fields.ApiFieldError), e:
            return HttpBadRequest({'success':False,'code': 666, 'message':e.args[0]})
        except ValidationError, e:
            # Or do some JSON wrapping around the standard 500
            return HttpBadRequest({'success':False,'code': 777, 'message':', '.join(e.messages)})
        except Exception, e:
            # Rather than re-raising, we're going to things similar to
            # what Django does. The difference is returning a serialized
            # error message.
            return self._handle_500(request, e)

    return wrapper
```

My problem here, i can't grab the self.my_field value to put in mon_dic, i always have data object, not value...

thx for help

EDIT : Add my_field global variable, and then grab value from bundle that's it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am not understanding what you want to do here. But `wrap_view` is for handling customer error responses. If all you want to do is return the data that was posted, you can set [always_return_data](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#always-return-data) to true in your `Meta`:

```
class Meta:
     always_return_data = True
```

Or if you want to control what data gets sent back, you can use the `dehydrate` method:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    bundle.data['custom_field'] = "Whatever you want"
    return bundle
```

Comment: I just want to have json back with success = True or False and id_data i try to inject... like : {'success':True,'id_data':1234} or {'success':False,'error': my_error,'id_data':1234} i don't want to see back all the data i inject